# org-mode html export with checkbox

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

Is it possible in org-mode, when you export to HTML, to have checkboxes beeing exported to HTML checkboxes?

If you have, for example, this org snippet:

```
- [ ] item a
```

You become code snipptes like this in HTML:

```
<li><code>[&#xa0;]</code> item a
```

But I would like to have this instead:

```
<li><input type="checkbox">item a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy:

```
(setq org-html-checkbox-type 'html)
```

Comment: Not really, I just grepped the source.

Comment: Yes, source is always the best documentation ;) But using not official documented features is a bit risky...

Comment: I tried it and it does not work, and I can not find such a variable in my org implementation (which is 8.2.5h-19-g0ceb68-elpa). Which version do you use?

Comment: I'm using git version. 8.2.5h. The var is in ox-html.el

Comment: M-x `customize-group` `org-export-html`. C-s `checkbox`

Comment: I don't get it. I added http://orgmode.org/elpa to package-archives to get latest org (even switched to org-plus-contrib), now having 8.2.5h-25-gc5d88f-elpaplus, but still no org-export-html. Already guessed it would be in ox-html.el. However, looking into org-mode.git that variable exists in line 979. I don't understand what the elpa version really is... Do I have to install org from git directly?

Comment: Yes, I always install from git. git gets merged into ELPA only from time to time.

Comment: Did not get it working, installation from git was somehow broken (e.g. group org-export-html was empty). And I have three machine types, one running ubuntu, one debian and the third windows, where I do not trust the latter will create 'make autoloads' correctly. Furthermore ox-reveal was then broken, not finding package org-8.0. And then there was this old org elpa bug, forcing me to install org from clean emacs (emacs -Q). All in all, that's not worth the time, so I will wait for elpa to be update. And not to forget the trouble with git using submodules. But thank you so far for your help.